# Derive an exponential value from a for loop's index

Tags: math

I have a collection of objects that will animate onto screen. I want the random delay of each animation to progressively grow depending on where the item is in the collection.

At the moment I can do this linearly fairly easily like so (Swift).

```
let proportionThroughContents = CGFloat(Double(idx) / Double(allNodes.count))
let delayRandomiserBaseValue: CGFloat = 40
let delayRandomiserGrowthValue: CGFloat = 60
let delayRandomiserValue = UInt32(delayRandomiserBaseValue + (delayRandomiserGrowthValue * proportionThroughContents))
```

I actually want some mathematical function to give me a bit of a hockey-stick like effect, where items in the middle still have low values, but items toward the very end get much higher values.

This may be more a mathematical question rather than a programming one, but I feel like this might be common enough to warrant it being here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible options. The simplest is probably a quadratic like a `x^2 + b x + c`, where x is your proportion and a, b, c are appropriate constants. In code you would need to write this as `a*x*x + b*x + c`.

For true exponential functions you want `k exp(l x)` in code `k * Math.exp(l*x)`.

Choosing the constants is the trickier bit. To get the same initial rates for quadratic just choose `b = delayRandomiserGrowthValue` and `c = delayRandomiserBaseValue`. You could then choose the `a` value depending on how much longer you the delay to be. `a + b + c` would give you the maximum delay.

```
let proportionThroughContents = CGFloat(Double(idx) / Double(allNodes.count))
let delayRandomiserBaseValue: CGFloat = 40           // c
let delayRandomiserGrowthValue: CGFloat = 60         // b
let delayRandomiserQuadraticValue: CGFloat = 60      // a
let delayRandomiserValue = UInt32(delayRandomiserBaseValue
       + delayRandomiserGrowthValue * proportionThroughContents 
       + delayRandomiserQuadraticValue * proportionThroughContents * proportionThroughContents  )
```

For exponential `k` is the initial value and `l*k` is initial growth rate. The final delay would be `k e^l`.

```
let proportionThroughContents = CGFloat(Double(idx) / Double(allNodes.count))
let delayRandomiserBaseValue: CGFloat = 40           // k
let delayRandomiserGrowthValue: CGFloat = 60         // 
let l: CGFloat = delayRandomiserGrowthValue / delayRandomiserBaseValue  // l
let delayRandomiserValue = UInt32(delayRandomiserBaseValue * Math.exp(l*proportionThroughContents))
```

With these value `l = 60/40 = 1.5` and the maximum delay would be `40*exp(1.5) = 179`.

Comment: Thanks for going to the extra effort of applying this to my code sample!

Comment: @Salix_alba using the exponential function, is there a way to "move" the curve further towards the end? I have perhaps 200 objects, and I want the last 5 or so to be much slower than the prior.

Comment: You might want something more like tan( 2 x / pi). This tends to infinity as x tends towards 1.